# Making a website for a church and need don't know what technology to use for calendar

Tags: web-development, calendar

So its been about two years since I've done any web development and recently I've been asked to redesign and create a my church's website. Since its just composed of basic pages holding info theres nothing really technical about them. My only concern is the calendar section, I'm wondering what technology should I use for the calendar in order for someone at the church to be able to update events on the calendar site.

Answer (score 2):

There is a drupal distribution called [OpenChurch](https://www.drupal.org/project/openchurch) which can get you started. It probably has a lot more than you need though e.g.

- calendar/events
- blog
- gallery
- social media integration
- podcast page for sermons, etc.

But you could switch-off the stuff you don't need. I have played with it in the past for a project.

You can also self-host as it is opensource.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a static web site generator such as the Python ones listed [here](https://www.fullstackpython.com/static-site-generator.html). This would let you have a source page, (in plain text/markdown), for them to edit and then a script to publish it to the server.

- Python is Free and most/all of the tools listed in the linked article are as well so no costs. *So no financial burden*
- Python *and the associated tools* can run on many platforms *from Raspberry Pi up* including older hardware *often what is available*
- Once it is all set up the technical knowledge required is minimal.
- The church can use the blogging facility to post thoughts for the day/week/month easily.

I would specifically recommend [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/quickstart.html) with [Invoke](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/publish.html#invoke) *to publish it*, [Nikola](https://getnikola.com/) or [Hyde](http://hyde.github.io/) are also good for the site generation.